# Put multiple values in arrays from cvs file

Tags: java, arrays, csv

Values are separated with comma, following format:

```
Country,Timescale,Vendor,Units
Africa,2010 Q3,Fujitsu Siemens,2924.742632
```

I want to make array for every value. How can I do it?

I tried many things, code below:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        country[0] +=",";
        String[] Krajina = country[0].split(",");
```

Comment: By "cvs" file, can we assume you meant "CSV" file, i.e. a Comma-Separated-Values file?

Comment: What do you mean by "make array for every value"? If you have e.g. 2 lines of input, what do you want the result to be, i.e. what variables, with what data, do you expect to end up with?

Comment: there is 30 values for country 30 for Timescale 30 for Vendor 30 for units... i want to have array with 30 values for country another one for Timescale etc.... and yes I meant Comma-Separated-Values file.. screenshot https://imgur.com/a/gyiENR6

Comment: Java is an **Object-Oriented** language. Use it!! Don't create 4 parallel arrays. Create a class with 4 fields, then have a *single* array of those objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define your arrays before processing your file :

```
String[] country = new String[30];
String[] timescale = new String[30];
String[] vendor = new String[30];
String[] units = new String[30];
```

And while reading lines you have to put the values in the defined arrays with the same index, to keep the index use another variable and increase it at every iteration. It should look like this:

```
int index = 0;

while (true) {
    if (!((line = br.readLine()) != null)) break;
    String[] splitted = line.split(",");
    country[index] = splitted[0];
    timescale[index] = splitted[1];
    vendor[index] = splitted[2];
    units[index] = splitted[3];
    index++;
}
```

Since your csv would probably include headers in it, you may also want to skip the first line too.

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to be talking about is utilizing what is otherwise known as ***Parallel Arrays*** and is generally a bad idea in this particular use case since it can be prone to **OutOfBounds** Exceptions later on down the road. A better solution would be to utilize a Two Dimensional (2D) Array or an ArrayList. Never the less, parallel arrays it is:

You say an array size of 30, well maybe today but tomorrow it might be 25 or 40 so in order to size your Arrays to hold the file data you will need to know how many lines of that ***actual*** raw data is contained within the CSV file (excluding Header, possible comments, and possible blank lines). The easiest way would be to just dump everything into separate ArrayList's and then convert them to their respective arrays later on be it String, int's, long's, double, whatever.

> **Counting file lines first so as to initialize Arrays:**

One line of code can give you the number of lines contained within a supplied text file:

```
long count = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\MyDataFiles\\DataFile.csv")).count();
```

In reality however, on its own the above code line does need to be enclosed within a **try/catch** block in case of a **IO Exception** so there is a wee bit more code than a single line. For a simple use case where the CSV file contains a Header Line and no Comment or Blank lines this could be all you need since all you would need to do is subtract one to eliminate the Header Line from the overall count for initializing your Arrays. Another minor issue with the above one-liner is the fact that it provides a count value in a ***Long Integer*** (long) data type. This is no good since Java Arrays will only accept **Integer** (int) values for initialization therefore the value obtained will need to be cast to **int**, for example:

```
String[] countries = new String[(int) count];
```

and this is only good if ***count*** does not exceed the **Integer.MAX_VALUE** - 2 (2147483645). That's a lot of array elements so in general you wouldn't really have a problem with this but if are dealing with extremely large array initializations then you will also need to consider **JVM** Memory and running out of it.

Sometimes it's just nice to have a method that could be used for a multitude of different situations when getting the total number of raw data lines from a CSV (or other) text file. The provided method below is obviously more than a single line of code but it does provide a little more flexibility towards what to count in a file. As mentioned earlier there is the possibility of a Header Line. A Header line is very common in CSV files and it is usually the first line within the file but this may not always be the case. The Header line could be preceded with a Comment Line of even a Blank Line. The Header line however should always be the first line before the raw data lines. Here is an example of a possible CSV file:

***Example CSV file contents:***

```
# Units Summary Report 
# End Date: May 27, 2019

Country,TimeScale,Vendor,Units
Czech Republic,2010 Q3,Fujitsu Siemens,2924.742032
Slovakia,2010 Q4,Dell,2525r.011404
Slovakia,2010 Q4,Lenovo,2648.973238
Czech Republic,2010 Q3,ASUS,1323.507139
Czech Republic,2010 Q4,Apple,266.7584542
```

The first two lines are Comment Lines and Comment Lines always begin with either a Hash (#) character or a Semicolon (;). These lines are to be ignored when read.

The third line is a Blank Line and serves absolutely no purpose other than aesthetics (easier on the eyes I suppose). These lines are also to be ignored.

The fourth line which is directly above the raw data lines is the Header Line. This line may or may not be contained within a CSV file. Its purpose is to provide the Column Names for the data records contained on each raw data line. This line can be read (if it exists) to acquire record field (column) names.

The remaining lines within the CSV file are Raw Data Lines otherwise considered data records. Each line is a complete record and each delimited element of that record is considered a data field value. These are the lines you want to count so as to initialize your different Arrays. Here is a method that allows you to do that:

***The fileLinesCount() Method:***

```
/**
 * Counts the number of lines within the supplied Text file. Which lines are
 * counted depends upon the optional arguments supplied. By default, all
 * file lines are counted.<br><br>
 *
 * @param filePath     (String) The file path and name of file (with
 *                     extension) to count lines in.<br>
 *
 * @param countOptions (Optional - Boolean) Three Optional Parameters. If an
 *                     optional argument is provided then the preceeding
 *                     optional argument MUST also be provided (be it true
 *                     or false):<pre>
 *
 *      ignoreHeader    - Default is false. If true is passed then a value of
 *                        one (1) is subtracted from the sum of lines detected.
 *                        You must know for a fact that a header exists before
 *                        passing <b>true</b> to this optional parameter.
 *
 *      ignoreComments  - Default is false. If true is passed then comment lines
 *                        are ignored from the count. Only file lines (after being
 *                        trimmed) which <b>start with</b> either a semicolon (;) or a
 *                        hash (#) character are considered a comment line. These
 *                        characters are typical for comment lines in CSV files and
 *                        many other text file formats.
 *
 *      ignoreBlanks    - Default is false. If true is passed then file lines
 *                        which contain nothing after they are trimmed is ignored
 *                        in the count.
 *
 *                        <u>When a line is Trimmed:</u>
 *                        If the String_Object represents an empty character
 *                        sequence then reference to this String_Object is
 *                        returned. If both the first & last character of the
 *                        String_Object have codes greater than unicode ‘\u0020’
 *                        (the space character) then reference to this String_Object
 *                        is returned. When there is no character with a code
 *                        greater than unicode ‘\u0020’ (the space character)
 *                        then an empty string is created and returned.
 *
 *                        As an example, a trimmed line removes leading and
 *                        trailing whitespaces, tabs, Carriage Returns, and
 *                        Line Feeds.</pre>
 *
 * @return (Long) The number of lines contained within the supplied text
 *         file.
 */
public long fileLinesCount(final String filePath, final boolean... countOptions) {
    // Defaults for optional parameters.
    final boolean ignoreHeader = (countOptions.length >= 1 ? countOptions[0] : false);
    // Only strings in lines that start with ';' or '#' are considered comments.
    final boolean ignoreComments = (countOptions.length >= 2 ? countOptions[1] : false);
    // All lines that when trimmed contain nothing (null string).
    final boolean ignoreBlanks = (countOptions.length >= 3 ? countOptions[2] : false);
    long count = 0;   // lines Count variable to hold the number of lines.

    // Gather supplied arguments for optional parameters
    try {
        if (ignoreBlanks) {
            // Using lambda along with Ternary Operator
            count = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).filter(line -> (ignoreComments
                    ? (!line.trim().startsWith(";") && !line.trim().startsWith("#"))
                    && line.trim().length() > 0 : line.trim().length() > 0)).count();
            if (ignoreHeader) {
                count--;
            }
            return count;
        }

        if (ignoreComments) {
            // Using lambda along with Ternary Operator
            count = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).filter(line -> (ignoreBlanks ? line.trim().length() > 0
                    && (!line.trim().startsWith(";") && !line.trim().startsWith("#"))
                    : (!line.trim().startsWith(";") && !line.trim().startsWith("#")))).count();
            if (ignoreHeader) {
                count--;
            }
            return count;
        }

        else {
            count = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).count();
            if (ignoreHeader) {
                count--;
            }
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("fileLinesCount() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return count;
}
```

> **Filling the Parallel Arrays:**

Now it time to create a method to fill the desired Arrays and by looking at the data file it look like you need three String type arrays and one double type Array. You may want to make these instance or Class member variables:

```
// Instance (Class Member) variables:
String[] country;
String[] timeScale;
String[] vendor;
double[] units;
```

then  for filling these arrays we would use an method like this:

```
/**
 * Fills the 4 class member array variables country[], timeScale[], vendor[], 
 * and units[] with data obtained from the supplied CSV data file.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param filePath (String) Full Path and file name of the CSV data file.<br>
 * 
 * @param fileHasHeader (Boolean) Either true or false. Supply true if the CSV 
 * file does contain a Header and false if it does not.
 */
public void fillDataArrays(String filePath, boolean fileHasHeader) {
    long dataCount = fileLinesCount(filePath, fileHasHeader, true, true);

    /* Java Arrays will not accept the long data type for sizing
       therefore we cast to int.   */
    country = new String[(int) dataCount];
    timeScale = new String[(int) dataCount];
    vendor = new String[(int) dataCount];
    units = new double[(int) dataCount];
    int lineCounter = 0;    // counts all lines contained within the supplied text file

    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("DataFile.txt"))) {
        int indexCounter = 0;
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            lineCounter++;
            String line = reader.nextLine().trim();
            // Skip comment and blank file lines.
            if (line.startsWith(";") || line.startsWith("#") || line.equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            if (indexCounter == 0 && fileHasHeader) {
                /* Since we are skipping the header right away we 
                   now no longer need the fileHasHeader flag.   */
                fileHasHeader = false;
                continue;   // Skip the first line of data since it's a header
            }
            /* Split the raw data line based on a comma (,) delimiter. 
               The Regular Expression (\\s{0,},\\s{0,}") ensures that
               it doesn't matter how many spaces (if any at all) are 
               before OR after the comma, the split removes those 
               unwanted spaces, even tabs are removed if any.
            */
            String[] splitLine = line.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}");
            country[indexCounter] = splitLine[0];
            timeScale[indexCounter] = splitLine[1];
            vendor[indexCounter] = splitLine[2];
            /* The Regular Expression ("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") below ensures
               that the value contained within what it to be the Units 
               element of the split array is actually a string representation
               of a signed or unsigned integer or double/float numerical value.
            */
            if (splitLine[3].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                units[indexCounter] = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[3]);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>An invalid Units value (<b><font color=blue>" + 
                        splitLine[3] + "</font></b>) has been detected<br>in data file line number <b><font " +
                        "color=red>" + lineCounter + "</font></b>. A value of <b>0.0</b> has been applied<br>to " + 
                        "the Units Array to replace the data provided on the data<br>line which consists of: " +
                        "<br><br><b><center>" + line + "</center></b>.", "Invalid Units Value Detected!", 
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                units[indexCounter] = 0.0d;
            }
            indexCounter++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("fillDataArrays() ethod Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

To get the ball rolling just run the following code:

```
/// Fill the Arrays with data.
fillDataArrays("DataFile.txt", true);

// Display the filled Arrays.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(country));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(timeScale));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vendor));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(units));
```

Comment: Such a waste these answers usually get ignored

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when using I/O

The following code should help you out:

```
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> timeScales = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> vendors = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> units = new ArrayList<>();

//use try-with resources
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] parts = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    countries.add(parts[0]);
    timeScales.add(parts[1]);
    vendors.add(parts[2]);
    units.add(parts[3]);
  }

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

for (String country: countries) {
  System.out.println(country);
}

for (String scale: timeScales) {
  System.out.println(scale);
}

for (String vendor: vendors) {
  System.out.println(vendor);
}

for (String unit: units) {
  System.out.println(unit);
}
```